# scanf with pointers, references, structures and functions

Tags: c++, eclipse

I can't find the answer to this (what should be simple) question.

I want to simply call a function that allows me to input the members of a structure within the function, go back to main, and print out the saved data.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "structTest1.h"

typedef struct boxes{
    int width;
    int length;
    int depth;
}boxSpecs;

void getBoxData(boxSpecs boxRecord);

//MAIN--------------------------------------
int main(void){

boxSpecs record[10];
  setbuf(stdout,0);

  getBoxData(record[0]);

  printf( "Box data is: Width = %d, Length = %d, Depth = %d \n", record[0].width, record[0].length, record[0].depth );


}//-------------------------------------

//structTest1.h
//function----------------------------

void getBoxData(boxSpecs boxRecord){

    printf("Enter box width: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord.width );
    printf("Enter box length: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord.length );
    printf("Enter box depth: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord.depth );
}//---------------------------------


//input: 
//1
//2
//3

//output:
//Box data is: Width = 0, Length = 4676696, Depth = 275260

//what I want:
//Box data is: Width = 1, Length = 2, Depth = 3
```

Can anyone explain why I get these results? And what I'm missing to get my desired results?

I'm trying to learn about structures and pointers and references and implement them all into one program. I have searched for an answer to this and I either can't find one, or I don't understand their question/answer/ or how to apply it to my problem.

Thanks in advance.
Grim

Comment: `bottleData` ? What's that? And what's the relation with this and C++?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Please indicate any line which is not C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator , The whole program appears C like with printfs and scanfs( I know they can be used in C++). Also, it dosen't have the iostream header which made me think that OP mistakenly tagged that C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use pointers like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct boxes{
    int width;
    int length;
    int depth;
}boxSpecs;

void getBoxData(boxSpecs* boxRecord);

int main(void){
    boxSpecs record[10];
    setbuf(stdout,0);
    getBoxData(&record[0]);
    printf( "Box data is: Width = %d, Length = %d, Depth = %d \n", record[0].width, record[0].length, record[0].depth );

}
void getBoxData(boxSpecs* boxRecord){
    printf("Enter box width: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord->width );
    printf("Enter box length: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord->length );
    printf("Enter box depth: \n");
    scanf("%d", &boxRecord->depth );
}
```

Comment: not in C++, here references are the poison of choice.

Comment: @Lubo thank you this is correct. I suspected the pointers exactly as you said, except for the "&boxRecord->width" vs my "&boxRecord.width". Could you, or anyone please explain the difference?

Comment: If you are accessing members of a struct directly you use dot boxRecord.width but if you are accessing members of a struct via pointer you are using arrow boxRecord->width. For more information take a look at this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: @Lubo Thank you very much. I am now a slightly better programmer because of you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems:-

1) use reference to struct.

```
void getBoxData(boxSpecs boxRecord){
```

replace it with

```
void getBoxData(boxSpecs& boxRecord){
```

2)Wrong variable used.

```
void getBoxData(boxSpecs boxRecord){

    printf("Enter box width: \n");
    scanf("%d", &bottleData.width ); <<What is bottleData, it should be boxRecord.width
    printf("Enter box length: \n");
    scanf("%d", &bottleData.length );
    printf("Enter box depth: \n");
    scanf("%d", &bottleData.depth );
}
```

Comment: My apologies, the "bottleData" was from my problem code, and the above code is a simplified version. The problem remains the same though.

Comment: @Grim: Re-check your code before submitting it here, especially for debug-questions, where you should always supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thus, you can avoid such embarrassing gotchas.